# using subprocess.call method

Tags: python

Python version: '2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:07:21) \n[GCC 4.4.3]'

I have this:

```
>>> ss = subprocess.call("ls -z", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How do I get the error message now ?

This does not work:

```
>>> for i in subprocess.PIPE:
...     print i
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `shell=True` and `"ls -z"` instead of `["ls", "-z"]`? It's not relevant to your problem, but generally, using the shell when you don't need to is a bad idea, as is passing command lines and hoping you got the escaping right so they get parsed into the list you had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That combo of options doesn't work very well. Communicate() will read stdout, stderr and wait for the program to terminate.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ls -z", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
assert proc.returncode == 0, 'i am sad'
print out
print err
```

If you want to read stdout line by line as the program runs, you can create your own thread to babysit stderr or pipe stderr to stdout.

Comment: I know I could Popen. I was wondering how would I do what I want to do with just subprocess.call ?

Comment: call() doesn't give you access to the pipes - its for cases where you want the user to see the output or you pipe to a file. its just not the right tool for the job if you want to process the output streams.

Comment: This doesn't explain the actual error. `subprocess.PIPE` is just a magic constant that tells the `subprocess` functions "create a new pipe and use it here" when you pass it. (It happens to be -1, but that's not important.) So, iterating that magic constant won't do anything useful.